# Expokit project ImagePicker work in expo but not working in build apk

Tags: react-native, expo

Expokit project ImagePicker work in expo but not working in build apk. This code did not respond in apk but working in expo. Why could it be?

```
pickFromGallery = async () => {
        const permissions = Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL;
        const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(permissions);

        console.log(permissions, status);
        if (status === 'granted') {

            let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
                allowsEditing: true,
                aspect: [4, 4],
            });

            if (!result.cancelled) {
                this.setState({ photo: result });

            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Did you write the code now after `expo eject`?

Comment: I did of course.